# id attribute in nested Java class mapped as MongoDb ObjectId()

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Following structure:

```
@Document 
public class Palace {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Location location;
    // additional attributes, getter, setter 
}
```

.

```
public class Location {
    private String id;
    // additional attributes, getter, setter
}
```

As far as I understand the concept of ObjectId, there can be only one ObjectId (_id) in a MongoDB document and it must be at the root level of the document. But when inserting data via Spring Boot 1.5.14 I get the followng structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b05387a8db58e0001d38851"),
    "location" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae712d1b2b197000132cd9b"),
    }
}
```

My question is: Is this the expected behaviour in spring-data-mongo? I would have expected the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b05387a8db58e0001d38851"),
    "location" : {
        "id" : "5ae712d1b2b197000132cd9b",
    }
}
```

If I annotate the Location id with @Field

```
public class Location {
    @Field("id")
    private String id;
    // additional attributes, getter, setter
}
```

then the Document is saved as expected, but querying with repository method

```
getPalaceByLocationId()
```

won't give any results.

Comment: Try `getPalaceByLocation_Id()` with `@Field`. See if it works?

Comment: `getPalaceByLocation_Id()` has the same result. Maybe this is a bug in spring-data-mongo, or the magic how to identify a MongoDb ObjectId is searching for ID fields in nested classes which is imho wrong.

Comment: getPalaceByLocation_Id() works for me when you have `@Field("id")`. Cross check.

Comment: How are you setting id field of location? are you setting it urself?

Comment: Yes, calling setId()

Comment: trying to get a minimal running service with an integration test on a git repo

Comment: I managed to set up a small service reproducing the issue. In the repo there is a Palace with a **Location containing a plain id**, and a **Location2 containing @Field("id") id**. Integrationtest for `getPalaceByLocationId()` is green, `getPalaceByLocation2Id()` is red. Hope this helps to reproduce. [github.com/d-baer/spring-data-mongo-example](https://github.com/d-baer/spring-data-mongo-example)

Comment: checkout my answer. have edited a bit

Answer (score 1):

Some insights into `id` field. id field is treated a bit differently in spring-data-mongodb.

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.M1/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling).

Extending the documentation for your case, when you declare an id like this

```
public class Location {
    private String id;
    // additional attributes, getter, setter
}
```

It  is stored as `_id` in database.  You can cross check by looking into the database.  The same is true when you annotate it with `@Id`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b31fad36a19cc45db205056"),
    "location" : {
        "_id" :  ObjectId("5ae712d1b2b197000132cd9b")
    }
}
```

5ae712d1b2b197000132cd9b is the id you had set using `location.setId()`. Internally it is converted to `ObjectId` and stored as `_id`.

But when you add `@Field` annotation, things change. Let's assume you add an annotation like this

```
@Field("id")
private String id;
```

Then the document looks like this in database.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b31fad36a19cc45db205056"),
    "location" : {
        "id" :  "5ae712d1b2b197000132cd9b"
    }
}
```

With this the problem is you cannot retrieve by id. Because when you write 
 `findPalaceByLocationId` or `findByLocation_Id` it(spring-data) tries to look for `_id` field which doesn't exist.

Only way around this is just use it like this

```
@Field
private String id;
```

or just

```
private String id;
```

This will create `_id` in database and you can do `findByLocationId`

I know it is a bit sketchy. But that is how it works.

And regarding

> As far as I understand the concept of ObjectId, there can be only one
>   ObjectId (_id) in a MongoDB document and it must be at the root level
>   of the document.

that is incorrect.

A small info table regarding mapping

```
Field definition         Resulting Id-Fieldname in MongoDB  

String id                      _id  
@Field String id               _id  
@Field('x') String id           x    
@Field('id') String id          id (InAccessible)   
@Id String x                   _id  
@Field('x') @Id String x       _id
```